# Not sure how to handle the destructor (Large vertex array in a class used as data source for other instances of the same class)

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, constructor, destructor

This makes me nervous. It works but, did I just created a subtle memory leak?

Here is the story:

I have a base class that stores vertices in a vertex array for use in OpenGL stuff. My intent is to store vertex data only once into a master object and then create instances of it and I want instances to read vertex data from the master object while keeping their own transformation matrices.

[image: Declaring a pointer to a vector array]

I declare a pointer to a vector array as private (since I do not want it being manipulated by anyone else except siblings)

The tricky part is I am forced to use a constructor with a default value of pointer-to-TypeGeometry.

[image: constructor declaration using default parameter]

If the object is constructed by passing it a pointer to a sibling object then this new object does not use a vertex array of its own. If it's constructor is passed the nullptr then the object creates it's own vertex array.

As you can see in the images I have to use the 'new' operator whenever the object is a master, but if I add a delete command in the destructor everything breaks.

If I omit the delete command everything works, but I worry for memory leaks. Should I worry ?

[image: define vertexARRAY (*VertexArray)]

[image: Constructor definition]

HERE is the issue:
if I enable this destructor it fails.
[image: destructor]

Running fine with the destructor DISABLED. Notice only three objects were created but there are multiple calls to the destructor.
[image]

Now see what happens when the destructor is ENABLED:
[image]

Comment: sounds like you could use [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

Comment: I just tried the shared pointer way, but now it fails instantly. It doesn't even finish constructing the first object:

Is this right: I use -----> shared_ptr < vector < TypeCartesian> > VertexArray (new vector < TypeCartesian>);

Comment: Why are you posting screenshots of your code instead of copy-pasting it ?

Comment: I think it would be a cleaner design to have a separate "data" class, instead of having one class that behaves differently depending on a flag.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have a memory leak because you don't `delete` memory allocated with `new`.

To fix this, you should just check if this is the master geometry in the destructor:

```
TypeGeometry::~TypeGeometry() {
    if (isMaster) delete VertexArray;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the first thing I did and it fails this way. The data is destroyed and I get an exception (I added some screenshots above)

It works only if I neglect the destructor, hence the quandary.

Comment: Are you copying or assigning `TypeGeometry` objects anywhere? You should declare the necessary functions or delete the implicitly generated ones.

Comment: It seems as the object is passed around between functions by reference during routine operations, the destructor is being called, but those calls are not the correct time to destroy the object.

Deleting the array in one of those fake destructor calls causes the data to be lost. The program continues to run and tries to access the array data which is now garbage memory and an exception occurs.

Comment: @ThomasAn Is it possible that the master object is destroyed before any of the non-masters referring to it?

Comment: No object copying or assignments anywhere. Three objects are created and then directly manipulated using their public methods.

Comment: @Angew In this test run there are no instanced objects at all. This is all happening with three master objects.

Comment: @ThomasAn Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please. There are far too may `Bye` outputs for just 3 objects...

Comment: If you change the destructor to print out "Bye" only when `isMaster`, then you'll see if you attempt a double-delete.

Comment: @TartanLlama Yes, the destructor is still being called repeatedly.
What's happening is, one of the objects is used as a camera object. I have to pass the camera object to a function. The compiler copies the object internally and the copied object thinks it's a master. When the scope runs out it's destructor is being called and acts as if it's the real object.

Comment: @ThomasAn that's why I said to write a correct copy constructor and assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see program is crashing because of deleting pointer more than once . You have 2 options :

1. use smart pointers like

   std::shared_ptr < std::vector < TypeCartesian>  > VertexArray
2. Check in destructor if that memory area is deleted on not :

   TypeGeometry::~TypeGeometry() 
       {
           if (isMaster && VertexArray != NULL) 
           {
              delete VertexArray;
              VertexArray = NULL;
           }
       }

Comment: If I go with option (2) the program will not crash, but it will not work either. The data will be safely deleted but prematurely having nothing to show.

What I suspect happening is that as I pass the object as a parameter to a function, the compiler makes copies of it to work in local scope. When the scope expires the local copy dies, but since it's a copy it has the master flag turned on.

Comment: that might be the case , you can go for 1st option .Its always safer in such cases , wehn ownership is not clearly defind , go for smart pointer.

Comment: I din't know about this type of pointer :-) and it looks promising by reading about it ... but it doesn't compile on gcc with the C++11 flag. I get an error: 'shared_ptr' in namespace 'std' does not name a type|

Comment: Have you added <memory> header file ?

Comment: @mystic_coder "when ownership is not clearly defined, go for a smart pointer". I'd say that's the case when you should *not* go for a smart pointer. Smart pointers exist to model ownership semantics.

Comment: Maybe its opinion , depends on person to person , I usually go for shared_ptr ,they are safe when ownership are not very clear , still you want to avoid memory leaks

Comment: ok. I added the <memory> include. It compiles. 
But now it fails instantly.

Instead of:
VertexArray=new vector<TypeCartesian>;

Now I use:
shared_ptr < vector < TypeCartesian> > VertexArray (new vector < TypeCartesian>);

Comment: Now remove any delete satements with VertexArray  .

Comment: @ThomasAn Please refer below sample usage of shared_ptr

Comment: #include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   //cout << "Hello World" << endl;
   std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int> >  intVec(new std::vector<int>());
   
   for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
   {
    intVec->push_back(i);
   }
   
   for(std::vector<int>::iterator i = intVec->begin();i != intVec->end();++i)
   {
     std::cout<<(*i)<<std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}

Comment: To be honest I'd probably use unique_ptr and std::move here if the intention is to give the object ownership.  It makes ownership more explicit than shared_ptr.

Answer (score 0):

Success !
(This was an all nighter, but I finally got somewhere thank to all comments and ideas posted. Thank you, thank you, thank you ! )

I did not have to use smart-pointers in the end.
The crux of the matter was that I was making function calls passing the class objects by value. Since I did not explicitly have a copy constructor the compiler was copying all the private variables verbatim (including the 'isMaster' flag).

The solution (as suggested) was two fold:
A) To make my own copy constructor and make sure the isMaster flag is NOT copied over. This way the destructor is not getting fooled.
B) Stop passing class objects by value. This was sloppiness of my part.

This turned out to be a trivial solution, but was too blind to see it.